# How can I receive an email when an upstart monitored script respawns?

Tags: upstart

My upstart config looks something like this

```
start on filesystem
stop on runlevel S

respawn

exec /path/to/my/script
```

When this script dies and is respawned I would like to receive an email. Is this possible, or am I using the wrong tool for the job?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could write a post-start stanza to send e-mail(s).

```
# An Upstart script to manage the foo service
respawn

post-start script
    echo "my-foo service started at `date +"%F %T.%N"`" | mail -s "My-foo Service Started" me@mydomain.org
    echo "my-foo service started at `date +"%F %T"`" | mail -s "My-foo Service Started" them@theirdomain.org
end script

exec -u foo-user /usr/local/bin/foo
```

Comment: But that would be run at every start, right? I think the question is only after a respawn, as opposed to a normal start.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `mail` command inside your script or write a wrapper script that does that and then calls your script. Then you'd have Upstart use your wrapper script.

```
echo 'Script scriptname respawned' | mail -s "respawn notice" foo@example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Write another job that will start on the `stopped` event for the job you are monitoring. Inside this job you can check `EXIT_CODE` and take action accordingly, e.g. :

```
# /etc/init/service_alert.conf
start on stopped myservice

task

script
    env >> /var/log/service_alert.log
    [ $EXIT_STATUS -ne 0 ] && echo "Env: $(env)" | mail -s "Alert $JOB is down!" page@example.com 
end script
```